# My view is not rendering in controller but works in route when calling view in route

Tags: laravel

I am updating a laravel application where in admin panel I need to add new view. when I call view in routes to file it works fine, but when I can call view using controller its gave me authentication that I am restricted and not authorized now I don't know what the other developer did in middleware that all the other functions are working fine, but my new method throw me authentication error. Maybe it listed the name of methods in a file no new methods can't be created like interfaces but he didn't use the interfaces. Then why new method can't be called in the controller method

Routes:

```
Route::group(array('module'=>'Manufacturer','namespace' => 'App\Modules\Manufacturer\Controllers'), function() {

    Route::get('manufacturer','ManufacturerController@index');
    Route::get('manufacturer-view','ManufacturerController@show');
    Route::get('manufacturer-create','ManufacturerController@create');
    Route::post('manufacturer-save',['as' => 'manufacturer-save', 'uses' => 'ManufacturerController@store']);

Route::get('manufacturer-specifications', 'ManufacturerController@manufacturerSpecifications');


 Route::get('manufacturer-specifications1', function () {
        return view('manufacturer::updated_manufacturer_views.manufacturer-my-specs');
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
class ManufacturerController extends Controller
{

    /**
      Class Constructor calling ACL
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('acl');
    }

    /**
      SUPER ADMIN :  index() function renders the Manufacturers listing page in Admin.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('manufacturer::list');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('manufacturer::new');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

            return Redirect::to('manufacturer')->with('message', $msg); 
    }
   public function manufacturerSpecifications(){


        $data['user'] = Users::find(Auth::user()->id);

        return view('manufacturer::updated_manufacturer_views.manufacturer-my-specs', $data);
    }
```

ACL Middleware:

```
class AclMiddleware
{

    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            $notifications = Notification::where('for_user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                                           ->where('read_status','no')
                                           ->count();

            $notificationsList = Notification::where('for_user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                                           ->where('read_status','no')
                                           ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                           ->get();

            $groupNotificaitonsCount = Notification::where('for_user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                                           ->where('read_status','no')
                                           ->where('group_id','!=','NULL')
                                           ->where('notify_type','invite')
                                           ->count();

            if($groupNotificaitonsCount){
                Session::put('notifications.groups.count',$groupNotificaitonsCount);
            }else{
                Session::put('notifications.groups.count',0);
            }

            if($notifications){
                $notificationsCount = $notifications;
                Session::put('notifications.count',$notificationsCount);
                Session::put('notifications.list',$notificationsList);
            }else{
                Session::put('notifications.count',0);
            }            

            if( Auth::user()->user_type==='manufacturer_standard' || Auth::user()->user_type==='manufacturer_paid' || Auth::user()->user_type==='architect' ){
                $manufacturer = Manufacturer::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
                $questions = Questions::where('manufacturer_id',$manufacturer->id)
                             ->count();
                if($questions){
                    Session::put('questions.count',$questions);
                }            
            }

//            echo Auth::user()->id;exit;

        }

//        if(Session::has('dropdownDivisions')===false)
//        {
//            Session::put('dropdownDivisions') = DB::table('divisions')
//                                                        ->select('code','name')
//                                                        ->where('status','active')
//                                                        ->orderBy('code','asc')
//                                                        ->get();
//        }

        if(Auth::check()){
            $curentUserRole = Auth::user()->user_type;
            $requestArr = explode('/', $request->path());
            $requestUrl = $requestArr[0]; 
            $havePermissions = DB::table('acl_user_permissions')
                                ->join('acl_resources', 'acl_user_permissions.resource_id', '=', 'acl_resources.id')
                                ->where('acl_resources.route_name',$requestUrl)
                                ->where('acl_user_permissions.user_type',$curentUserRole)
                                ->count();
            if($curentUserRole==='admin'){
                $suggestRefLink = 'admin-dashboard';
                $suggestRefText = 'Admin Dashboard';
            }elseif($curentUserRole==='manufacturer_standard'){
                $suggestRefLink = 'manufacturer-dashboard';
                $suggestRefText = 'Manufacturer Dashboard';
            }elseif($curentUserRole==='manufacturer_paid'){
                $suggestRefLink = 'manufacturer-dashboard';
                $suggestRefText = 'Manufacturer Dashboard';
            }elseif($curentUserRole==='normal'){
                $suggestRefLink = 'user-dashboard';
                $suggestRefText = 'User Dashboard';
            }elseif ($curentUserRole==='architect') {
                $suggestRefLink = 'manufacturer-dashboard1';
                $suggestRefText = 'Manufacturer Dashboard1';
            }
            else{
                $suggestRefLink = '/';
                $suggestRefText = 'Home Page';
            }
            if(!$havePermissions){
                $data['link'] = $suggestRefLink;
                $data['text'] = $suggestRefText;
                return view('restricted',$data);
            }

        }else{
                return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It works fine

```
 Route::get('manufacturer-specifications1', function () {
        return view('manufacturer::updated_manufacturer_views.manufacturer-my-specs');
    });
```

But it thorough me the error

```
Route::get('manufacturer-specifications', 'ManufacturerController@manufacturerSpecifications');
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: authentication error that not allowed to visit the page.. its some kinda middleware  issue... same view works when i use it directly in route but throws authentication error that am not allowed to visit the page when use same view in controller and access it through route

Comment: exactly i missed to edit database and provide permission in acl_user_permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you `forgot` to provide `permissions` in `acl_user_permissions` table.